# GitHub - Green lines next to text?

Tags: github

This is my first GitHub, I want to write a report but this green line keeps popping up next to my text and I don't want it to do so. This is what my text should be but it appears like this: https://gyazo.com/f593db78a387623fcad31c744ac9a120

How can I control this?

## System Hardware Final Report

The project designed shows the functioning behind computer's.

The topics covered will include:

- Introduction to Binary & Logic Gates

  - Commonly Used Parts
  - Logic Functions
- The Timing Signal Generator
- The Bus, Arithmetic Unit and Program Counter
- Data Registers and the Memory Address Register
- Program Memory
- The Control Signal Generator

The outcome of this project will enable one to build a computer with a CPU (central processing unit) that can do simple
instructions such as moving data from one register to another and performing simple arithmetics.

### Introduction to Binary & Logic Gates

#### Breadboard

The breadboard will be used to setup the components and all circuits. It is divides in 8 parallel coloumns and contains 5 columns that
   provides power. In fact, the breadboard is made up of two important supply connections: the `VCC` for the red
   line and the `GND` for the blue line. The holes are all connected row-by-row in lines of 5.

[image: The breadboard]

#### Switches

Answer (score 5):

This happens when you make changes to a file (this is called a diff), then preview it. Green indicates something was added, while red indicates something was removed. Committing the changes will not make the lines stay in the file.